How to save model and load model in ReactJS
im follwing the transfer learning course of tensorflowjs on youtube. Im trying to make a model recognize some picture i upload. The problem is when i close window or reload, the model is load from scratch and the data it just learn lost. How to save the model after it "transfer learning" and load it when i access that page. (Im loading MobileNet from google for the first time). Thanks u guys !!!
Follwing the tensorflowjs course in youtube, i can train a model to recognize some image. But when reload the window, it is disposed and i have to retrain. (Im making a web to recognize user face, each user when login can register their face for some task)

The youtube course is Google AI for JavaScript developers with TensorFlow.js .

You need to save your model somewhere, and now tensorflow do it easily.
A good place to save a model is indexeddb for efficiency :
await model.save('indexeddb://my-model');

When your app is loaded you can check if the model already exist.
const loadModel = async (indexddbAdress) => {
    try{
      return await tf.loadGraphModel('indexeddb://' + indexddbAdress);
    } catch (error) {
      // model not in indexddb, maybe start the training process
    }
  }

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load
EDIT

Save to a cloud

To save directly to a cloud you will need a custom URL, the model will be sent as a blob and the implementation will be specific to the cloud API.
See this answer which provide an example using google function with Google API to Firebase : Best practice to save a TensorflowJS model to firebase storage?
Reference :

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#io.http
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd


Real word app

For the specific case of face recognition, if you want to create a real word app, I recommend you to save only the signature of the face. The face recognition process usually follow those steps :

face detection -> apply face recognition model to a picture that gives you the coordinates of faces in the image
From the coordinates of the faces -> get pictures of the faces (and only the faces)
face recognition -> apply face recognition model to each face image to get the signature of the faces
compare the faces signatures with the faces signatures on your DB and find the best match

You can get examples for this process from this library :
https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js
The library uses an outdated version of tensorflow.js but the process is still relevant.

Thanks, can you provide some examples ? And do you mind if i ask you how to save the model to some cloud infras like google cloud ? I want it to be saved whenever an user let the model learn his face. I want the model loaded even if i enter my web from another computer ... Thanks !!!
